# Receive Image data as JSON and injecting it into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am packaging an image into jSON and sending it to the client  .... On the client side I wish to display this data as a image ...

I am not sending the Image URL via JSON ... I am trying to send the whole image data itself

JSON image data that I receive in the client looks like this:

```
PNG  Ûâ\IÂØ>ó4ã¯wcÏLÓQÆÝîHâèÖnò)©£M¡ÀÍ.j3µx¼ê#Ì{ÞÂ±NÔÃïj$­©N¨eÃyßÆR$id'|ýpøcå{ãyY'àþ½b|äô¹¨:Óç}@ÖÀdõÉ­Ä
```

Comment: its not impossible with json only , try to using another tools like http://www.west-wind.com/WestwindWebToolkit/docs/_2zw0px5cb.htm

Comment: @Haim: from the article: `but provides you the ability to create Services that can serve more than just JSON data` so the service is NOT serving JSON when it is in binary mode

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can accomplish this with data URL's in all browsers save for IE7 and below. The basic format is this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7">
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

Comment: the image data you have here is a image/gif and will not show if you change its signature to image/png.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how elegant your solution is, but you could encode the image as BASE64 and inline it using:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64_ENCODED_DATA_HERE">
```

It might also be noteworthy to say, that BASE64 encoding adds about ~33% overhead. Instead, you might create some temporary directory on your server, where you store such images and delete them after the request?

Comment: You cannot use `<code>` - instead use the button with the {} or use a backtick: `

Answer (score 4):

You cannot send binary data to the browser inside JSON.

You can use b64 encoding and the DataURI ([MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs)) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)) in a browser that understands it

Since the comments that came after my post all have an actual example, here is one from Wikipedia:
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />`

Alternatively convert to [SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/SVG_2_DOM/JSON_Constructors) which is also textual